# Tensorflow: Input shape change when RNN cell is called

Tags: python, input, tensorflow, shapes

I was digging into the Tensorflows source code in order to fix a input shape problem I have with their Translation model. The model creates a seq2seq model, which again calls a [rnn model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py) . On line 226, my RNNCell is called, but the input sent in is not the same as the one caught by the **call** method in my cell. Am I missing something? (Note that call_cell() is a lambda function)

`print(_input)` in the rnn.py gives the following output:

> Tensor("encoder0:0", shape=(8, 8), dtype=int32)

while `print(inputs)` in the RNNCell gives:

> Tensor("model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding_lookup:0", shape=(64, 1000), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)

As you can see, the input is not the same, but I cannot see what else that is happening. My code breaks when call_cell is called in the rnn.py file. Is the tensor affected by some operations I can't see, or is it simply another tensor the RNNCell receives?